# two key string dictionary from array of objects

Tags: swift3

I'm currently doing this to get an array of strings with users phone numbers :

```
 if let phoneNumbers = contacts.map({$0.phoneNumber}) as? [String] { }
```

Contact Object:

```
class Contact {

    var name: String!
    var phoneNumber: String!
}
```

How can instead of getting an array of string with the phone numbers get an array of strings with each of the contacts name and phone number? I want to include both values in the string array instead of just the phone number.

Thanks

Edit:

Current output is something like this `["3453534534", "34534535345"]` where those are phone numbers.

The output that I hope to achieve is something like this `["john" : "12312312", "robert" : "32423423423"]`

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Could you explain it better, and also give us some sample input and output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I'm sorry Alex. I just added some sample output and desired output

Comment: Are you aware that output is not an Array?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Got it. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: `class Contact {
    let name: String
    let phoneNumber: String
    required init(name: String, phoneNumber: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber } }`

Answer (score 1):

```
var dulce = [String: String]()
contacts.forEach {
    dulce[$0.name] = $0.phoneNumber
}
```

This did the job in the least amount of code possible!